SRAM Rival 1 Levers reference for replacement Hoods
I'm about to change the shifters hood on my Rove ST 2019 (Rival 1 shifters).
From the question here : Replacement Hoods for SRAM Rival 1 Levers it seems strange the correct replacement part is the one for Rival 22 hood (SRAM ref 00.7918.010.000), but it seems that Will Haley had troubles fitting them correctly.
I'm asking the question here as I cannot add my question to the original one, and maybe someone else had the same question.
Will Haley said he had bump/protrusion, I guess that the things he had in mind (arrows on the picture).

Did you end up finding a solution since last year?
I asked SRAM for a part number, to confirm the 00.7918.010.000. No reply yet.
Thanks for your insights!

The shifter mouldings are identical for Rival 22, Apex 1, Rival 1 etc. Rival/Apex1 have different branding but the shape is the same as are the lever internals on the right for 22 and 1. The left shifter is empty but has space to have the shifter internals installed. So it is not at all strange that the hoods are the same part for 1 vs 22. The main concern is Hydro or Cable, as these are significantly different shapes.

Your red arrows are not pointing to the correct hole at the top. Your tape is covering where those go.

Yes you are right for the upper arrows, I see it now. The tape is the original one, I'll change it soon. Do you recommend not to put the tape that high on the lever?

Thanks for the info on the levers ! Gave me confidence in ordering new hoods :)
